# How can I get a SQL stored procedure to work with SELECT parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

Here is an excerpt from a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddLogin]
    @gameid INT,
    @serverid INT, 
    @memberid VARCHAR(15)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @lastLoginTime datetime
    DECLARE @lastLoginDate datetime
    DECLARE @isRelogin bit

    SELECT 
        @lastLoginDate = LoginDate, 
        @lastLoginTime = LoginTime 
    FROM 
        Logins 
    WHERE 
        LoginDate = (SELECT MAX(LoginDate) 
                     FROM Logins 
                     WHERE MemberID = @memberid AND GameID = @gameid);
```

When I run this stored procedure, and output `@lastLoginDate` and `@lastLoginTime` I'm getting null.

However after much frustration and testing I found that when I hard-code values for the input parameters `@memberid` and `@gameid` it works fine. In fact, if I hardcode `@memberid` and leave `@gameid` parameterized it still works fine.

It has something to do with the fact that `@memberid` is a `varchar` it is coming out as null in the excerpt below, whereas I can leave the `@gameid` parameter in because that is an `int`. Is this correct? What am I doing wrong?

Again if I run the exact same code except hardcode '1234' instead of the `@memberID` parameter

```
SELECT @lastLoginDate = LoginDate, @lastLoginTime = LoginTime 
FROM Logins 
WHERE LoginDate = (SELECT MAX(LoginDate) 
                   FROM Logins 
                   WHERE MemberID = '1975A' AND GameID = @gameid);
```

it all works.

Comment: What's the datatype of `MemberID` in the **table**? Could it be `CHAR(n)` and thus padded with spaces? Or something like that .....

Comment: please include some sample data and show us how do you execute the procedure

Comment: Thanks for your reply @marc_s. It is a varchar(15) just as I had it in the sp.

Comment: Actually I think I may have solved it. Turns out, when I had SQL Server script the execution it was executing
@memberid='''1975A'''

instead of
@memberid='1975A'

When I changed it to single quotes it started working. I could swear that was breaking before. Well it's solved for now :). I still have to debug the rest of it. Thanks!